# Temporary server using current IP

Tags: windows, server, xampp, ip, localhost

I've got a XAMPP running on my computer and I've got dynamic IP.
However I would like to temporary change my computer to a server, using current IP, so someone from outside will be capable of entering my server.

How can I do it?

Right now if write down in the browser *localhost* it will open the appropriate page with my content, but if I write *127.0.0.1* or my current IP address, it's saying that "This webpage is not available". Why?

Comment: This sounds like a routing question. You have to make yourself clear how a network actually works. So from what system are you trying to reach your "server" and what route is in between?

Comment: Oh, and also you will have to open the post your http server listens on in your package filter, if you are using one ("firewall").

Comment: I just have got a simple home router.

Comment: Then to connect "from the outside" to a system inside your home network (your "server") you have to take care that packages sent to the http port of your routers external ip address are routed through to that server. This is called "port forwarding". You have to configure it on your home router. But keep in mind that _everyone_ out there will be able to connect. So you only (if at all) want to do that if your server has been secured very well. Which is nearly impossible with a MS-Windows system...